# Need to bind a <h:link> into my backing bean

Tags: java, html, jsf

Quick question:
I need to bind an `<h:link>` into a backing bean.
However I can't seem to find the appropiate HTML component?
I know for instance an `<h:commandLink>` can be binded to an *HtmlCommandLink* and a `<h:outputLink>` similarly to an *HtmlOutputLink*, however I need specifically the equivalent to `<h:link>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [`HtmlOutcomeTargetLink`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlOutcomeTargetLink.html).

---

For learning and debugging purposes, you could also just bind it to `Object` or `UIComponent`. When JSF has set it, then just check the `getClass()` value in a debugger or by `System.out.println()` to learn about the concrete component implementation.

Answer (score 0):

looks like HtmlOutcomeTargetLink is the component class for h:link.

Comment: sorry -- was responding while you were.

Comment: Dont worry, its never an excess to confirm. Thanks to you both :)